# Veracode Rejecting Encryption Algorithm - Which Should I be using?

Tags: java, encryption, veracode

I inherited a Java (Spring) project in its maintenance phase, that just went through Veracode for the first time, and the only `High` flaw we have remaining is one reporting a "weak or broken" encryption algorithm.  I'd prefer to spend the time learning more about cryptography, but this project is live in the wild so I need to start with a more immediate solution to get this application secured.

Here is the line Veracode is reporting specifically:

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("PBEWITHSHA1ANDDESEDE");
```

Veracode offers no information on:

- Why this algorithm is broken/weak
- Which algorithms might make for sufficient substitutes
- Any other concerns to be aware of when selecting an appropriate algorithm

What could I replace `"PBEWITHSHA1ANDDESEDE"` with?  Would that necessitate other refactors, or is it as simple as a string literal swap?  I'd love to give more specification to help us narrow down which encryption algorithm would be best, but since Veracode isn't providing any, the only specification is, "encryption algorithm that satisfies Veracode."

Comment: PBE is not that great, SHA-1 is considered broken (but not for all use cases) and Triple DES is also not that great. There are many possible replacements. I'd recommend PBKDF2 with SHA-256 and AES, but I don't know if there is such an algorithm option.

Comment: Considering both SHA1 and DES are broken at this point, it makes sense that they are rejecting it.  Try SHA256 with AES?

Answer (score 2):

> Why this algorithm is broken/weak

It is mainly broken because it uses PBKDF1 instead of PBKDF2 (or another/better Password Based Key Derivation Function). Using triple DES is also a small weakness as it may only offer about 80 bits of security in certain settings. SHA-1 is broken and it may well be a reason why Veracrypt mentions "weak or broken" encryption algorithms, but actually the use of SHA-1 in a key derivation function is considered secure.

> Which algorithms might make for sufficient substitutes

If you want to rely on build in functionality then `PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_128` would be a direct replacement. Other schemes could include other derivation functions such as bcrypt, scrypt or Argon2 and other modes of encryption such as AES-GCM.

> Any other concerns to be aware of when selecting an appropriate algorithm.

CBC as used in above schemes is not secure for transport mode security unless a MAC (message authentication) is added; it is only secure for in-place encryption where padding oracle attacks don't apply. This is also the case for your current scheme though.

Your scheme still relies on password security, which can be very weak in itself. Generally you want to use a high iteration count / work factor and / or make very sure that the password / pass phrase has sufficient strength.

No PBE scheme (including the one you are already using) is an *implementation requirement* for Java compatible JRE's. Although alternate JRE's probably will provide an implementation I would not count on it being present or correctly implemented in Java versions of other suppliers.

Comment: Veracode has identified `PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_128` as a "broken or risky cryptographic algorithm."  We are considering contacting Veracode to ask them how to resolve this or what alternatives they recommend.

Comment: As with any password based crypto and CBC there are a lot of ifs and buts, but I would not call it broken.